# Executing command with spaces in one of the parts

Tags: go, exec

I am running a command through the [os/exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) package that is called like this:

```
out, err := Exec("ffprobe -i '/media/Name of File.mp3' -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv=p=0", true, true)
```

The function I have written to execute command line calls is:

```
func Exec(command string, showOutput bool, returnOutput bool) (string, error) {
    log.Println("Running command: " + command)

    lastQuote := rune(0)
    f := func(c rune) bool {
        switch {
        case c == lastQuote:
            lastQuote = rune(0)
            return false
        case lastQuote != rune(0):
            return false
        case unicode.In(c, unicode.Quotation_Mark):
            lastQuote = c
            return false
        default:
            return unicode.IsSpace(c)
        }
    }

    parts := strings.FieldsFunc(command, f)
    //parts = ["ffprobe", "-i", "'/media/Name of File.mp3'", "-show_entries", "format=duration", "-v", "quiet", "-of", "csv=p=0"]
    if returnOutput {
        data, err := exec.Command(parts[0], parts[1:]...).Output()
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        return string(data), nil
    } else {
        cmd := exec.Command(parts[0], parts[1:]...)
        if showOutput {
            cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
            cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
        }
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
    }

    return "", nil
}
```

The `strings.Fields` command splits the command on spaces and that is used as the string array to pass to the exec.Command function. The problem is that it is splitting the filename into different parts because of the space when that `filepath` needs to stay together. Even if I format the string array correctly so the `filepath` is in one part, the `exec.Command` still fails because there is a space. I need to be able to execute this script to honor the `filepath` as one argument with spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.

```
var parts []string
preParts := strings.FieldsFunc(command, f)
for i := range preParts {
    part := preParts[i]
    parts = append(parts, strings.Replace(part, "'", "", -1))
}
```

I needed to remove the single quotes from the arg passed into the exec.Command function.

Answer (score 3):

1. You may use `strings.Split(s, ":")` on special character like `:` and switch  `"` with back-tick,
   Like this working sample ([The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vPDLfNm7GS)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    command := `ffprobe : -i "/media/Name of File.mp3" : -show_entries format=duration : -v quiet : -of csv=p=0`
    parts := strings.Split(command, ":")
    for i := 0; i < len(parts); i++ {
        fmt.Println(strings.Trim(parts[i], " "))
    }
}
```

output:

```
ffprobe
-i "/media/Name of File.mp3"
-show_entries format=duration
-v quiet
-of csv=p=0
```

2. try print `cmd.Args` after `cmd := exec.Command("ffprobe", s...)` (remove `.Output()` ):

   for _, v := range cmd.Args {
   fmt.Println(v)
   }

something like this, to find out what happens to your args:

```
s := []string{"-i '/media/Name of File.mp3'", "-show_entries format=duration", "-v quiet", "-of csv=p=0"}
cmd := exec.Command("ffprobe", s...)

for _, v := range cmd.Args {
    fmt.Println(v)
}
cmd.Args = []string{"ffprobe", "-i '/media/Name of File.mp3'", "-show_entries format=duration", "-v quiet", "-of csv=p=0"}
fmt.Println()
for _, v := range cmd.Args {
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

see:

```
// Command returns the Cmd struct to execute the named program with
// the given arguments.
//
// It sets only the Path and Args in the returned structure.
//
// If name contains no path separators, Command uses LookPath to
// resolve the path to a complete name if possible. Otherwise it uses
// name directly.
//
// The returned Cmd's Args field is constructed from the command name
// followed by the elements of arg, so arg should not include the
// command name itself. For example, Command("echo", "hello")
func Command(name string, arg ...string) *Cmd {
    cmd := &Cmd{
        Path: name,
        Args: append([]string{name}, arg...),
    }
    if filepath.Base(name) == name {
        if lp, err := LookPath(name); err != nil {
            cmd.lookPathErr = err
        } else {
            cmd.Path = lp
        }
    }
    return cmd
}
```

---

Edit 3- Try this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command(`ffprobe`, `-i "/media/Name of File.mp3"`, `-show_entries format=duration`, `-v quiet`, `-of csv=p=0`)
    for _, v := range cmd.Args {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
    fmt.Println(cmd.Run())
}
```

Comment: I've tried that. Even if I format the string array correctly with the arguments separated the way they should be, the exec.Command function seems like it splits that filepath again because it contains a space.

Comment: That's doing the exact same thing. The issue is not the formatting of the "parts" array. The issue is that once I've gotten the "parts" array exactly how I need it, one of the strings still contains a space and the exec.Command function is not handling that. I've added the function I'm using to break up the command the way I want. It accomplishes the same thing as your code except you don't have to add any other characters to the command. It separates by spaces but still honors quotes.

Comment: Try Edit 2 may be helps to find out what happens inside `exec.Command`

Comment: Try this new Edit 1 and 3

Comment: It looks like exec.Command is keeping the arg with the space surrounded by single quotes, but I'm still getting: exit status 1. No error message. And when I run it normally I get output in seconds for how long the .mp3 file is.